# Nurse recertification in the US

Tags: usa, education, certification

When moving to the US what's the procedure to get a Registered Nurse certification for someone who's been working as a nurse in one of the Eastern European countries?

Comment: AFAIK go to college and do it all again.

Comment: @juergend Anything more specific or detailed?

Comment: Further infos here: https://www.ncsbn.org/. Seems like you can take an evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@juergend shared already in the comments a [very useful link](https://www.ncsbn.org/171.htm) :

> Each state in the U.S. is responsible for the licensure of nurses
>   within that state. Variations exist among the states. State specific
>   licensure information is available on [board of nursing websites](https://www.ncsbn.org/contactbon.htm).
>
> To ensure public protection, all boards of nursing **require a candidate
>   for licensure to pass an examination** that measures the competencies
>   needed to perform safely and effectively.